Allow overflow-y to be visible but overflow-x to be auto without absolute child cause vertical scrolling
I have an element that can overflow horizontally, so user can scroll horizontally.
In the overflow children is an absolute element that sits below it's parent, but when applied, this then causes vertical scrolling.
So, I need horizontal scrolling but prevent scrolling/clipped/hidden vertical content.
This is a very basic example of the problem I am facing...


.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  background: red;
  overflow-x: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 700px;
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
}

.relative {
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: purple;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% + 20px);
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  right: auto;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="relative">
      <div class="absolute">
        absolute element
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



What I actually want is the following, where content is still horizontally scrollable but the absolute element is viewable and prevents the vertical scrolling.

In my actual markup, the absolute element varies in height, and there are multiple, or sometimes none in the single parent, so I can't realistically set a fixed height to a parent to prevent an absolute element from causing the vertical scrolling.
JSFiddle
